# SQL Query - Year by Year Growth of Sales

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have this result set from an SQL query. This result has come up by grouping the sales of tenant per year to get the total sales in yearly basis. Table is named TENANTSALES with columns: Tenant, date, sales etc.

```
TENANT      YEAR    SALES   
tenant 1    2014    2000    
tenant 1    2015    5000       
tenant 2    2013    1000    
tenant 2    2014    1500       
tenant 2    2015    800
```

I used this SQL query code to achieve the above result

```
select tenant, year(date), SUM(sales)
from tenantSales
group by tenant, YEAR(date)
```

What I need to complete the task is to add a column name Yearly growth where it will compare and compute for year by year growth of sales per tenant. Here's the sample correct / desired output

```
TENANT      YEAR    SALES    YEARLY GROWTH
tenant 1    2014    2000    
tenant 1    2015    5000       150%
tenant 2    2013    1000    
tenant 2    2014    1500       50%
tenant 2    2015    800       -46.67%
```

The formula is: ((Latest Year - Previous Year) / Previous Year) * 100

Example for Tenant 1:

((2015 sales - 2014 sales) / 2014 sales) * 100 = 150%

Ive tried to do this, adding the next year in the previous year's row to make it easy for me to compute for the two years sales, but I can't add up the sales of the latest year, only the year itself. Is there any way or proper way to do it?

```
select tenantcode, year(date), SUM(gsc), year(date) + 1
from dailymod
where tenantcode = 'cmbina13'
group by tenantcode, YEAR(date)
```

Your expert advice will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.tenant, t1.YEAR, t1.SALES,
    CASE WHEN t2.YEAR IS NOT NULL THEN
        FORMAT(
            CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), (t1.SALES - t2.SALES)) /
            CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), t2.SALES), 'p')
    ELSE NULL END AS "YEARLY GROWTH"
FROM
(
    SELECT tenant, YEAR(date) AS YEAR, SUM(sales) AS SALES
    FROM tenantSales
    GROUP BY tenant, YEAR(date)
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT tenant, YEAR(date) AS YEAR, SUM(sales) AS SALES
    FROM tenantSales
    GROUP BY tenant, YEAR(date)
) t2
ON t1.tenant = t2.tenant AND t2.YEAR = t1.YEAR - 1
```

Click the link below for a working demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e626/35)

**Late Update:**

You could also try the same approach using Common Table Expressions.  Here is what the above query would look like using this approach:

```
WITH cte AS(SELECT tenant, YEAR(date) AS YEAR, SUM(sales) AS SALES
            FROM tenantSales
            GROUP BY tenant, YEAR(date))
SELECT c1.*, CONVERT(varchar,
                 CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),
                     CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), (c1.SALES - c2.SALES)) /
                     CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), c2.SALES))) + '%' AS "YEARLY GROWTH"
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.tenant = c2.tenant AND c2.YEAR = c1.YEAR - 1
```

And here is another Fiddle where you can test this out:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e626/47)

Comment: Thanks so much! I will test both method and see what is better in terms of performance.

Comment: Hi Ricky, I updated my answer to use only the `CONVERT()` function, which SQL Server 2008 should be able to use.  Same output, slightly more verbose query.  Actually, Giorgi's suggestion to do the formatting in the app layer might make more sense for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using cte you can reuse your query. I am using window function because you can have some missed years. But if years are consecutive then you can join directly on year column:

```
with cte as(select tenant, 
                   year(date) y, 
                   SUM(sales) s,
                   row_number() over(partition by tenant order by sum(sales)) rn
            from tenantSales
            group by tenant, YEAR(date))
select c1.*, ((c1.s - c2.s) / c2.s) * 100 as grouth
from cte c1
left join cte c2 on c1.tenant = c2.tenant and c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
```

Or:

```
with cte as(select tenant, year(date) y, SUM(sales) s
            from tenantSales
            group by tenant, YEAR(date))
select c1.*, ((c1.s - c2.s) / c2.s) * 100 as grouth
from cte c1
left join cte c2 on c1.tenant = c2.tenant and c1.y = c2.y + 1
```

Comment: I would like to have this approach, but it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean under wrong? That it outputs null instead of empty string? That is the correct way to do it. You shoud have percents in numeric value and not as strings. Formats should be applied in client app.

Comment: The formula was implemented incorrectly. I was deviding by current year instead of prev year

Comment: Yeah, the formula is incorrect, after changing, and adding additional select query for c2, it partially work.

Comment: still having trouble at this part: select cte1.*,

Comment: I have already changed that. There should be `c1`. But never mind. Another user has just edited his answer with copy of mine. I will delete this.

Comment: I will vote this as useful though.. it actually work after editing. The other answer does not use cte, but simple left join and worked too.

Answer (score 1):

```
select tenant_id
      ,year
      ,sales
      , round((case when chk<>0 then ((sales-chk)/chk)*100  else 0 end),2)as yoy 
           from(
                select tenant_id
                      ,year
                      ,sales
                     ,lag(sales,1,0) over(partition by tenant_id order by year asc) as chk
                          from tenant)
```

Answer (score 0):

please consider my answer with analytical function.

```
select tenant ,year(date) ,sum(sales),
  format( ((sum(sales)/convert(float,lag(sum(sales)) over( partition by tenant order by tenant,year(date))))-1),'p')
from tenantSales
group by tenant , year(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below solution.

```
create table tenant_details
(tenant varchar(10),
year number(10),
sales number(10)
);

insert into tenant_details values ('tenant 1',2014,2000);
insert into tenant_details values ('tenant 1',2015,5000);
insert into tenant_details values ('tenant 2',2013,1000);
insert into tenant_details values ('tenant 2',2014,1500);
insert into tenant_details values ('tenant 2',2015,800);

commit;
```

SQL Query:

```
select tenant,year,sales,case when prev_sales is null then null else
                         to_char((sales-prev_sales)*100/prev_sales,9999.9) ||'%' end profit
                         from (
select tenant,year,sales ,lag(sales,1) over (partition by tenant order by year) prev_sales from tenant_details
);
```