# SQL BigQuery : Calculate Value per time period

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new to SQL on BigQuery and I'm blocked on a project I have to compile.

I'm being asked to find the year over year growth of sales in percentage on a database that doesn't even sum the revenues... I know I have to assemble various request but can't figure out how to calculate the growth of sales.

Here is where I am at :

[image]
Has Anybody an insight on how to do so?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: A couple of tips (though not an actual answer): Try to use standard SQL instead of legacy SQL, if you can, since it has more features, and use the NUMERIC type for financial data so that you don't lose precision when summing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Starting from what you have, group by product line to get this year and last year's revenue in each row:

```
#standardsql
with yearly_sales AS (
select year, product_line, sum(revenue) as revenue
from `dataset.sales`
group by product_line, year
),

year_on_year AS (
select array_agg(struct(year, revenue))
            OVER(partition by product_line ORDER BY year
                 RANGE BETWEEN PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS data
from yearly_sales
)
```

(2) Compute year-on-year growth from the two values you now have in each row

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT product_line, year, revenue, prev_year_revenue, 
  ROUND(100 * (revenue - prev_year_revenue)/prev_year_revenue) year_over_year_growth_percent
FROM (
  SELECT product_line, year, revenue, 
    LAG(revenue) OVER(PARTITION BY product_line ORDER BY year) prev_year_revenue
  FROM (
    SELECT product_line, year, SUM(revenue) revenue
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    GROUP BY product_line, year
  )
)
-- ORDER BY product_line, year
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your information (plus mine made up data for 2007) and I arrived here:

```
SELECT
  year,
  sum(revenue) as year_sum
FROM
  YearlyRevenue.SportCompany
GROUP BY
  year
ORDER BY 
  year_sum
```

Whose result is:

R   year    year_sum
1   2005    1.159E9
2   2006    1.4953E9
3   2007    1.5708E9

Now the % growth should be added. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863937/sql-query-year-by-year-growth-of-sales) for inspiration.

Let me know if you don't succeed and I will try the hard part, with no guarantees.